# Change first input based on second input, applying a function, using purrr´s map2

Tags: r, list, purrr

I'm wondering if it's possible to change, let's say `.x` based on `.y` applying `map2()` on the fly, applying a function.

Let's say I have two vectors with different lengths and want to fill shortest one with `NA`, in order to have same length in both vectors:

```r
vec1 <- seq(1, 3, by = 2)
vec2 <- seq(2, 3, by = 2)
```

Both solutions are valid:

1. `length(vec2) <- length(vec1)`
2. `` `<-`(length(vec2), length(vec1)) ``

But, what if I have vectors in lists, and want to apply `purrr`'s `map2`?

```r
l1 <- list(c(1,2), c(1,2))
l2 <- list(3, 3)
```

I have tried:

```r
library(purrr)

map2(l1, l2, ~ `<-`(length(.y), length(.x)))
```

but does not work. Any ideas how to assign a value inside `map2`?

PS: I'm trying to avoid using loops.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `` `length<-` `` rather than `` `<-` ``.

```r
purrr::map2(l1, l2, ~ `length<-`(.y, length(.x)))

# [[1]]
# [1]  3 NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  3 NA
```

which is equivalent to

```r
purrr::map2(l1, l2, ~ { length(.y) <- length(.x); .y })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(l2)) length(l2[[i]]) <- length(l1[[i]])
```